# How to get images from android camera in RGB?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-camera, tensorflow-android

I want to develop a machine learning program using Tensorflow, OpenCV and Android. I already trained my model and uploaded it to my mobile, but I am facing problems when I want to feed the image taken with camera. The problem is that the camera is taking pictures with the format RGBa (which has 4 channels) and my CNN input has only 3 channels (the shape looks like this 100, 100, 3). Also I want to develop the app that I will make inference on each frame, without the necessity to press a button or something like that. I should say that I am a newbie in Android development and this app would be only to provide a demo to my bachelor thesis.

My network input:

```
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, height, width, channels], name="X")
```

where height = width = 100 and channels = 3

and my android code looks something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame;
        Mat resizeimage = new Mat(100, 100, CvType.CV_32SC4);
        Imgproc.resize( inputFrame.clone(), resizeimage, new Size(100, 100));
        MatOfInt rgb = new MatOfInt(100, 100, CvType.CV_32SC3);
        resizeimage.convertTo(rgb,CvType.CV_32SC3);
        float[] rgbFloat = new float[(int)(rgb.total()*rgb.channels())];
        rgb.get(0,0,rgbFloat);
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, rgbFloat, INPUT_SIZE);

        inferenceInterface.run(new String[] {OUTPUT_NODE});
        int size = classes.length;
        float resu[] = new float[size];
        for(int i =0;i< size;i++){
            resu[i] = 0;
        }
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, resu);
        Log.d("result", convert(resu));
        return mRgba;
    }
```

How should I proceed?